# Reuse test suites for multiple branches in Jenkins?

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, jenkins

Currently I have two jobs for two SVN branches (stable and development) set up in Jenkins, in which one job compiles a workspace and the other runs a test suite on it. (So in total there are four Jenkins jobs.) The test suite job takes a number of hours to run (these are system tests for a fairly large system), so I want to split it up into separate jobs. This will give me all kinds of benefits like feedback on which tests fail often, and the possibility to run separate tests right from the Jenkins interface.

How can I go about splitting up the test suite job? If I split it into 10 different jobs, then I will get 10 jobs for each branch. Although that is not a problem by itself, if I add a system test, I need to add it to each branch, which seems tedious. Also if the details of a branch change, I have to edit all jobs belonging to it. And finally, what would be the best way to trigger the execution of these jobs?

I have looked through the plugins, and the only things I found that might help are the [Configuration Slicing Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin) and the [Bulk Builder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bulk+Builder+Plugin) Although these help with editing and running multiple jobs, they don't solve the 'add test to multiple branches' problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in [Jenkins: The Definitive Guide](http://www.wakaleo.com/books/jenkins-the-definitive-guide). In chapter 10.5 "Generating your Maven build jobs automatically" this exact problem is solved by generating the job config files using the [Maven-jenkins-plugin](http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Maven-jenkins-plugin).